# Is this hWnd a child of mine?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hwnd

How can I tell if an hWnd belongs to one of my child controls?

I want to do something like:

```
if(this.Controls.Find(hWnd) != null) return false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Win32 function for this: [IsChild](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/IsChild.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a great chance to use recursion.  Add this function to your parent class:

```
  private bool IsChild(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, System.IntPtr hWnd)
  {
     if(control.Handle == hWnd)
        return(true);

     foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control child in control.Controls)
     {
        if (IsChild(child, hWnd))
           return (true);
     }
     return (false);
  }
```

You can then use this function to search this parent class for any child controls with the specified hWnd:

```
this.IsChild(this, hWnd);
```

Comment: thanks!  I was hoping there was a faster way than iterating over child controls (especially if the hWnd belongs to a child of a child :) )